# Left digested peptides in speedvac for hours

Tags: proteomics, mass-spectrometry

I had done phosphopeptide enrichment of proteomic samples and digested the peptides with trypsin. However, I forgot and left the samples in speedvac to dry at 45 deg for way too long, about 10hrs. It does usually take a few hours to dry. Will it hamper my samples and the proceeding LC-MS analysis?

Another thing to ponder is that only one sample has a big round white powdery clump and the rest are transparent clear blobs, hard to see anything, as it should be. And this is also the tube which I eluted one extra time as well. If it is salt or detergent I don't think it would be that thick. Have any idea on what this could be? I will run it in the MS anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it's unlikely to work, to me, though I'm not an expert in this stuff. Interested to hear what the data look like though!

Comment: Thank you for responding and for your insight. I will run it in the MS soon and see. I hope it somehow works and will update on how it looks, fingers crossed.